# Xorg on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, xorg

First - thank you so much for OpenShift, it's an excellent service that I've been using for 3 years, and I'm very satisfied with it in its current form! This is a feature request, rather than a bug report.

I read that it is now possible to run Xorg without root privileges.

I'd like to run MOBAC and other apps that require an X display on my OpenShift gear.

Without access to /etc, nor superuser privileges, is it possible to install an Xorg binary?

Thank you for your help!
Peter

Comment: Hmm, I'm assuming you ended up here because there's a link on Openshift's website that recommends asking questions on Stack overflow. However, this site would only be appropriate for troubleshooting problems you've having using openshift, rather than feature requests. While someone here might know if this feature already exists, they probably won't be able to help get it added to the product. I think your request is best sent here: https://www.openshift.com/ideas, or head to their IRC channel and ask there (https://www.openshift.com/irc).

Comment: You're right: I asked here because OpenShift recommends it. I also think that other community members might be familiar with compiling Xorg to not use root privileges. I've asked on IRC and had some helpful advice to get port forwarding to work, but I'm now stuck with the XFS font server.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have the packages installed to run an X display on OpenShift Online.  OpenShift Online is meant as a headless server environment, running X would eat up memory very quickly.

Comment: MOBAC doesn't actually require an active X display, but it requires an X server to get a DISPLAY variable even when in command-line mode. The RAM available is still much larger than was typical back in the 80s-90s when X was first released!

Comment: We also do not have the packages installed for an xserver.